# Pong game Android onTouchListener?

Tags: android, touch-event

So basically I made the screen with 2 paddles and a very simple score board. I've been researching a little and found the onTouch method. But that only works for 1 paddle. How about 2 player? Is there a onTouch and drag method, because I want the player to touch the paddle and move it right or left. And lastly how can I do that for both of the paddles?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458042/Touch-handling-in-Android). `onTouchEvent` receives `MotionEvent` object, and you can handle multiple touches using `event.getActionIndex()` and `event.getPointerId()`. You should probably determine if you're moving tob or bottom paddle by initial touch coordinates, and then handle events properly (by moving paddle that matches PointerId for example)

Comment: Could this be used for both the paddles?
Or just 1, because if I do x = event.getX(); It would only go to 1 paddle (the x location)

Comment: Read the article I linked, there's whole section about multitouch. Yes, you can use it for two paddles, every event will be provided with pointer Id. So for example when user 1 touches his paddle, and then second user touches his, then move events from first user will have Id=1 and move events for second figer (of the other player) will have id=2. You'd only need to getX(), check if this is bottom or top paddle, link it to pointer Id and then with new events check which paddle you should move